# Adding an onChange event to a Dojo FilteringSelect

Tags: javascript, dojo

I tried added an onChange event that I want to fire every time a selection is made on the FilteringSelect but it doesn't seem to fire. I've trying having the action in the on function to be both change and onChange and neither working. I tried having onChange as a parameter of the FilteringSelect but that didn't work either.

I'm using Dojo 1.10.

```
require(["dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(FilteringSelect, Memory, dom, on) {
    var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
      id: "zoom",
      name: "zoom",
      value: "z",
      intermediateChanges: true,
      store: new Memory({
        data: [
          {name:"Zoom", value:"z"},
          {name:"50%", value:".5"},
          {name:"75%", value:".75"},
          {name:"100%", value:"1"},
          {name:"125%", value:"1.25"},
          {name:"150%", value:"1.5"},
          {name:"175%", value:"1.75"},
          {name:"200%", value:"2"}
        ]
      }),
      searchAttr: "name"
    }, "zoomDiv").startup();
    on(filteringSelect, 'change', function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried a fiddle of your code. What I found is that you need to separate the creation of `filteringSelect` and its `startup`. If they are separate, then it works fine (though the `value` is always undefined for obvious reasons). Although I don't know what's the reason for the same as in the examples on DOJO's site, they are in a single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dijit/form/FilteringSelect` as a strange API. The `onChange` is fired when the user type something in the textbox, when you select something in the list opened for auto complete, but *NOT* when you select something in the list from the opened using dropdown button.

For a consistent event you can watch the property `displayedValue`

```js
require(["dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(FilteringSelect, Memory, dom, on) {
    var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
      id: "zoom",
      name: "zoom",
      value: "z",
      intermediateChanges: true,
      store: new Memory({
        data: [{
          name: "Zoom",
          value: "z"
        }, {
          name: "50%",
          value: ".5"
        }, {
          name: "75%",
          value: ".75"
        }, {
          name: "100%",
          value: "1"
        }, {
          name: "125%",
          value: "1.25"
        }, {
          name: "150%",
          value: "1.5"
        }, {
          name: "175%",
          value: "1.75"
        }, {
          name: "200%",
          value: "2"
        }]
      }),
      searchAttr: "name"
    }, "zoomDiv");
    filteringSelect.startup();
    filteringSelect.watch('displayedValue', function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
      alert(property + ':' + newValue);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>
 <div class="tundra">
<div id="zoomDiv"></div>
</div>
```